# simple sql create table syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

this might end in a down vote but I can´t see trees because of forest:

running this sql query:

```
CREATE TABLE `fontFamilies` (
  `id` INTEGER NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NULL',
  `designer` INTEGER NULL,
  `firstLaunch` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastUpdate` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I get following error in http://sqlfiddle.com/

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NULL',
  `designer` INTEGER NULL,
  `firstLaunch` TIMESTAMP NU' at line 3
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: It works in sql fiddle. Are you sure?

Comment: @marc_s, in error there is mysql, and I can not reproduce this error on sqlfiddle

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri copy paste does not work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLFiddle uses mysql. Try setting **the size of `varchar`**:

```
CREATE TABLE `fontFamilies` (
  `id` INTEGER NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NULL',
  `designer` INTEGER NULL,
  `firstLaunch` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastUpdate` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

You can also add `insert` commands to the same window:

```
insert into `fontFamilies` values(217,'name',217,'1992-10-10 10:10:10','1992-10-10 10:10:10')
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't think you need to explicitly set the varchar length. It defaults (I think) to 255.

Comment: @AlvinThompson you can try it in SQL Fiddle (with mysql) and see if that true

Comment: I guess that's it! Is that mysql specific?

Comment: @AlvinThompson I think so

Answer (score 1):

You must set the size of VARCHAR .

```
    CREATE TABLE `fontFamilies` (
  `id` INTEGER NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NULL',
  `designer` INTEGER NULL,
  `firstLaunch` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastUpdate` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );
```

This will work .